# Nuxt3 Robots.txt - @nuxtjs/robots not generating robots.txt file

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, robots.txt, nuxtjs3

I'm building a Nuxt 3 project. I need my build to generate a robots.txt file, just like this package states it does -> https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module

After running "nuxt build" and/or "nuxt generate", the robots.txt does not appear in the output or public folders as I'd expect.

I'm definitely missing something and likely being an idiot here.. Does anyone know what I'm missing? Here's my code:

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0", 
    }
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
 target: "static",
  runtimeConfig: {
    NUXT_STORYBLOK_PRODUCTION_KEY: process.env.NUXT_STORYBLOK_PRODUCTION_KEY,
    public: {
      CDN: process.env.CDN,
      NUXT_STORYBLOK_PREVIEW_KEY: process.env.NUXT_STORYBLOK_PREVIEW_KEY,
      NUXT_DOMAIN_NAME: process.env.NUXT_DOMAIN_NAME,
    },
  },
  modules: [
    ...
    "@nuxtjs/robots",
  ],
  robots: {
    UserAgent: "*",
    Disallow: "",
  },
}
```

Comment: It should be `generate` and available in `dist` if I'm not mistaken. Otherwise you can always run `preview` and inspect the generated payload to double check.

Comment: Nvm, it's the `.output` directory rather.

Comment: It doesn't appear for me in ```output```. If it should appear there and I get no other responses on this question, it's likely I have a dependency conflict with another package and it may be a case of stripping down the project until I find the problem.

Comment: Tried to preview it? I doubt there is a conflict tbh.

Comment: Yep. Stil nothing. ```Build``` / ```Generate``` && ```Preview```, tried it all. No Robots file gets generated in that ```output``` folder or any of it's subfolders.

Comment: Got a repro like a public Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incompatible version of nuxt robots for your project. Ensure you are using version ^3.0.0. Any versions below this are not compatible with nuxt 3.

```
npm install @nuxtjs/robots@3.0.0
```

Then ensure your nuxt.config.ts looks similar to below. As John Overstreet mentioned above the simple method appears flawed.

I created a config folder in the root directory of my project and placed my robots.txt file within it:

```
export default {
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/robots', { configPath: "~/config/robots.config" }]
  ]
}
```

**You will also need to delete the robots.txt file from your public folder**

Build/Generate your project and go to '/robots.txt'

The file is generated dynamically upon request of the above route.

With mine and John's help above I hope this helps resolve your issues :)

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully installed this module on Nuxt 3, and I think there are a couple of things to note here.

The first is that I've never managed to get the module options for any module to work in Nuxt 3 the way you have shown (top-level options, according to the module docs):

```
  modules: [
    ...
    "@nuxtjs/robots",
  ],
  robots: {
    UserAgent: "*",
    Disallow: "",
  }
```

Have you tried the other options? You can also try using the [Robots Config](https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module#robots-config) file, or pass the options when declaring the module (from the README.md for the repo):

```
export default {
  modules: [
    // Simple usage
    '@nuxtjs/robots',

    // With options
    ['@nuxtjs/robots', { /* module options */ }]
  ]
}
```

The other thing is that I also do not see a generated robots.txt file anywhere after running the build or dev, but if I go to '/robots.txt' in the dev or build preview, I can see the output working as intended. Have you tried visiting the path?

It looks like something the server generates when the route is visited rather than a static file generated on build by default. I think you can change that in the options, but it's not something I need so I haven't dug into it.

Hopefully, that helps somewhat!

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think to be iso with the Nuxt 3 ecosystem it will be better to use this module:

`nuxt-simple-robots`

You can install it through `yarn add -D nuxt-simple-robots`

(In the same page you can find the modules for Sitemap as well and all SEO needed modules for Nuxt 3 SEO)

Here is the documentation about how to install it and work with it

https://nuxtseo.com/robots/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 0):

On Nuxt 3 this generates the default robots.txt file in dist, but setting the described parameters doesn't do anything (inline or not).

I manually modify my dist/robots.txt file before deployment.

Not ideal, but at least it generates the default file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me either. I tried all the methods.

1. As per the documentation with `npm install @nuxtjs/robots`.
2. I tried with version `npm install @nuxtjs/robots@3.0.0` and creating a `robots.config` file.

Both didn't work. Finally, I ended up creating a `robots.txt` file in the public folder.